# Specific off topic close question for technical questions?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Even though [technical implementation questions are off topic](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7/42), we [still have](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/620/if-a-community-site-hacker-could-hack-a-site-could-he-really-hack-a-moderators) a [few questions](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1006/manage-subscriptions-in-phpbb) that deal with technical aspects. *([List of all closed questions that aren't duplicates](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3Aquestion%20closed%3Ayes%20duplicate%3Ano))*

Mods can add a custom close reason for off topic and I think it'd be a good idea to do so. I understand that we still only have a handful of questions that are closed because of this, but it seems like a decent amount of closed questions in the future will be because of technical questions. We can make at most three custom off topic reasons, but we can also remove them if needed (doubtful this will happen).

Another idea would be to migrate these types to Webapps SE, since they have [some questions about forums](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forums).

Comment: It doesn't look like these are on topic at webapps. From their tour page, it lists as off topic: `Hosted scripts such as Wordpress.org and phpBB`.

Comment: @Andy I'm thinking that they meant no configuration file type things, not that using the website part of Wordpress was off topic but I'm not completely sure. There are some borderline questions still open, though. I see no reason to single them out unless the questions are about the hosting part of it.

Answer (score 5):

Technical implementation or system administration questions would be off topic on Web Applications.

We are a site for *users* of web applications, not developers, administrators or moderators.

If you want to migrate such questions anywhere then you might want to consider:

- [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com) for questions where you are hosting things on servers run by others.
- [Wordpress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) if the question is specifically about managing a Wordpress installation.
- [Drupal](http://drupal.stackexchange.com) if the question is specifically about managing a Drupal installation.
- [Joomla](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/) if the question is specifically about managing a Joomla installation.

There are other sites for specific CMSes that I can't remember.

Comment: I was originally thinking questions about the configuration done with the GUI, but Webmasters might be better.

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin - that's still not on topic for Web Apps. You're not a user, but an admin.

Comment: Disambiguation: I meant I was thinking that when I asked the question, not now. Thanks for the clarification, though! :)